# Unable to run a .Net website locally using the System.Web.Security namespace

Tags: security, asp.net-membership

I took over this 4.0  webforms website and got the exact same code from the former developer.

It runs fine on his local machine, but it craps out on my local machine having anything to do with the “System.Web.Security” namespace.

If I put a breakpoint where it is failing and try to fall into the code for that namespace, it won't let me go any further. It just simply will not execute anything to do with the namespace. This happens with all of the three major browsers

Since this forum does not allow any attachments, I can't show you anything more.

Does anybody have any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a simple permissions issue on our end not allowing my id to have access to the database.